# How to stop user highlighting and deleting text in an edit control?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7, ribbon

I have an Edit Control on a DevExpress Ribbon of type `TcxBarEditItem` which I am recording the keypresses of to update a "floating" listbox of possible functionality to fire.

For some reason, the `TcxBarEditItem` and it's parent classes' event handler's do not work at all like Delphi's vanilla equivalents, meaning I have to record these keypresses.

My question however, is how to record/or prohibit, the user doing things like pasting in loads of text, or highlighting and deleting loads of text?

The way in which these controls seem to work means using `String(TcxBarEditItem(control).EditValue)` (which is how I would access the control as it is a member of a Command class - `TS8RibbonCommand`) isn't actually indicative of the text in the edit control until the user clicks out of it.  I've tried doing loads of things like programmatically setting focus elsewhere and refocusing but nothing else seems to work bar recording the keypresses.

In the code snippet `mirroredJumpStart` is my copy of what the user is typing.  The `RefreshJumpStart` function takes a string value and iterates over all the different string values in a list and populates a Listbox using `AnsiContainsString`.

```
procedure TS8RibbonJumpStartEdit.KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
 begin
  if (Key in ['a'..'z']) or (Key in ['A'..'Z']) or (Key in ['0'..'9']) or (Key = ' ') then
   manager.mirroredJumpStart := manager.mirroredJumpStart + Key
  else if (Key = Chr(VK_BACK)) and (Length(manager.mirroredJumpStart) <> 0) then
   Delete(manager.mirroredJumpStart, Length(manager.mirroredJumpStart), 1);
  manager.RefreshJumpStart(manager.mirroredJumpStart);
 end;
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: If it were just a plain TEdit VCL control, I can give you tons of tips, but I have no clue about using an edit control in a ribbon - is this different than TEdit?

Comment: Is this edit control windowed? And did you ask devexpress?

Comment: It's miles different from a regular VCL component unfortunately, but our application is crawling with DevExpress components.  I'll head over to the DevExpress forums and ask them.  I'm pretty sure we're using a very very old version so I doubt it'll be supported but it's worth a shot!

Comment: Then that's stepping into a subject I barely know. You can use ribbons in Delphi 7? I've only seen them in D2010 and up

Comment: Yeah, it's by no means elegantly implemented though.  Out of curiosity, how would you go about disabling the user deleting chunks of text from a TEdit?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a standard TEdit control...

- You can limit the amount of text by using MaxLength property
- You can catch individual keystrokes by observing `Key` parameter in the event `OnKeyDown`

Just a couple little tips, not sure if it will help, because you don't say you're using the `TEdit`

Comment: It says in the question that it's not a `TEdit`. Since it is housed inside a ribbon it's quite likely that it's not even windowed.

Comment: I wasn't clear if `TcxBarEditItem` was supposed to be the Edit control or the Ribbon or a part of the Ribbon control